# VS Code não reconhece as cores no CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, visual-studio-code

Boa noite, pessoal. Queria tirar uma dúvida. Não sei se foi alguma atualização, mas percebi que arquivos em CSS não estão reconhecendo as cores digitadas, mas em HTML isso acontece normalmente. Achei que fosse uma config padrão, mas agora preciso baixar o Color Highlight pra conseguir essa mesma configuração em CSS.

[Representação do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IIr3.png)